# How to optimize the for-loop code for drawing voxel-respresented spheres from given sphere coordinates?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, voxel

randPoints is a list of 10,000 sets of (x,y,z) coordinate
xx, yy, zz are the product of meshgrid and have the shape of (201,201,201)

```
for j in range(len(randPoints)):
    #prepare coordinate x,y,z 
    xc_small = randPoints[j][0]
    yc_small = randPoints[j][1]
    zc_small = randPoints[j][2]

    #just unit conversion
    xcm = xc_small*1e-6
    ycm = yc_small*1e-6
    zcm = zc_small*1e-6

    #calculate f to make sphere of radius 0.5e-6
    f =  ((xx-xcm)**2+(yy-ycm)**2+(zz-zcm)**2 <= (0.5e-6)**2)
    
    #add 1 sphere into cube n
    n = n+f
```

This loop will keep adding spheres to n for 10,000 times.
This for loop takes around 10,000 seconds for 10,000 spheres. I wish to speed up the computation.
n would be 201*201*201 voxel-represented cube filled with 10,000 voxel-represented spheres.

more details on variables:

```
    x = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.5)
    y = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.5)
    z = np.arange(0, 2*50, 0.5)
    xx, yy, zz   = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
    n = np.ones((int(201),int(201),int(201)))
```

I think that the calculation of f is inefficient.

I tried 1.vectorization to calculate for-loop all at once. But the problem is it takes too much memory that the session crashed, or maybe my vectorizing code is not correct.
The code is:

```
#prepare all (x,y,z) into a vector for one-time computation
xc_small = np.array(randPoints_small)[:, 0]
yc_small = np.array(randPoints_small)[:, 1]
zc_small = np.array(randPoints_small)[:, 2]

#just unit conversion
xcm = xc_small*1e-6
ycm = yc_small*1e-6
zcm = zc_small*1e-6

#one-time computaion of f
f = ((xx[:, :, :, np.newaxis]-xcm)**2 + (yy[:, :, :, np.newaxis]-ycm)**2 + (zz[:, :, :, np.newaxis]-zcm)**2 <= (0.5e-6)**2)
n = np.sum(f, axis=-1)
```

I also tried 2.parallelization of the for-loop computation but it doesn't become faster.

Comment: small speed up would be to just directly access the element instead of using a `for j in range(len(randPoints)):` to instead do `for point in randPoints:` and change the `randPoints[j]` to `point`

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewRyan. `for point in randPoints:` makes my code a lot cleaner! Thank you. The reason I do the squaring is that it is the equation for a sphere in 3D. So any voxel satisfying the equation will be included in f. Then f will be added into my sphere-bank n.

Comment: why convert everything to millionths (`1e-6`)? why not convert the xx, yy, and zz (which is outside the loop I believe) to the non-millionth counterpart? (removing those conversion operations from the loop). Further if `(0.5e-6)**2` is going to be static why not have it as a variable to reference instead of doing the calculation each loop.

Comment: So you have two set of points, `randPoints` and a (201 x 201 x 201) meshgrid, and you are trying to calculate for each point `p` in the mesh, how many points from `randPoints` are within a sphere of `p`?